I am trying to connect 2 systems EAA nodes and expecting all the events get synch and displayed on to kibana1 and kibana2
I have connected 2 VApps which makes it as 2DC's system.
On DC1 I have added and Installed Elastic Search and EAA nodes and installed them, same goes with DC2. Now I want all the events from DC2 in DC1 and viceversa, but it's not happening.

However, consider DC1, I ran console consumer command for the target machine which is EAA2 of DC2. I could see all the events in the cmd prompt but not in Kibana. Kibana only displays the localhost's event and not DC2's events.

I have been trying to raise logstash logs but it is bind to log4j2.properties, I tried but no logs helped. In fact how to raise the logstash logs ?.
Any help would be appreciated.
